# Flutter Plugin BETTER_PLAYER notification click does nothing

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

i was given a task to fix the issue where audio notification when clicked does nothing but it should open the app and that specific screen. i searched better_player docs but found nothing their
does anyone here know how to fix this?
here the code for notification creation:

```
BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
      musicDetail.playLink,
      notificationConfiguration: BetterPlayerNotificationConfiguration(
        showNotification: true,
        title: musicDetail.songName,
        author: musicDetail.artist,
        imageUrl: musicDetail.image,
        activityName: "MainActivity",
      ),
    )
```

does it have some kind of listener that i have to attach with it?